# Error when build BlackBerry project use Eclipse?

Tags: blackberry

I'm using Blackberry plugin for Eclipse.

I have just encountered a problem today.

I can't build any Blackberry project successful.

The error is:

```
Packaging project BlackBerryDVRRemote
C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\bin\rapc.exe -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BlackBerryDVRRemote deliverables\Standard\5.0.0\BlackBerryDVRRemote.rapc -sourceroot=D:\PHONG\BlackBerry WorkSpace\WorkSpace1\BlackBerryDVRRemote\src;D:\PHONG\BlackBerry WorkSpace\WorkSpace1\BlackBerryDVRRemote\res -import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar D:\PHONG\BlackBerry WorkSpace\WorkSpace1\BlackBerryDVRRemote\bin
Warning!: No entry points found
Warning!: No definition found for exported static routine: .main(String[])
Packaging project BlackBerryDVRRemote succeeded (took 0.932 seconds)
```

These Blackberry projects was built successful yesterday, but today is not.

In the "Bin" folder I don't see any *.class file.

I Right click on the project and choose propertiers-->Java build path, I see "Default output folder" is BlackBerryDVRRemote/bin.

I Right click on the project and choose "Run/Debug As Simulator/Device", I see no happen.

Please help me to fix it,

Many thanks !

---

When i restart eclipse, i see the following error:

Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".

Exception stack tracke:

```
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3770)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.getData(Widget.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.close(WorkbenchWindow.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.WindowManager.close(WindowManager.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$16.run(Workbench.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.busyClose(Workbench.java:927)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$15(Workbench.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$23.run(Workbench.java:1100)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.ja
```

Please help, thanks all !

Comment: Have you installed the newest JDK?

Comment: have you installed properly ??? has it worked before or this is the first application you are running in it ?

Comment: @Alexander Farber: I have just updated last version of JDK but the problem still exist.

Comment: @Arun Kumar Munusamy: I have been working with BlackBerry for 1 year. And I have just encountered this problem recent days.

Comment: @Levanphong7887: No problem man.. my experience.. i cant able to judge this blackberry.. unexpected things happens many times. without deleting the workspace, delete the eclipse and re-install it.. thats it.. problem solved..

Answer (score 1):

thanks too: I have the same issue with Juno & BlackBerry resource editor.

By removing the project from the workspace and re-importing it, it works!